# Scaling with docker-compose and appending a number to the hostname?

Tags: docker, containers, docker-compose

I've got a `docker-compose.yml`:

```
master:
  build: .

slave:
  image: master
  hostname: slave
  command: run_slave
```

How can I make `docker-compose scale slave=5` generate machines with unique hostnames?

...e.g. something like this:

```
slave1
slave2
slave3
slave4
slave5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to set the hostname to that value.

If you need a unique identifier, I would use the unique container id, which you can get by running `$(hostname)`.

Answer (score 8):

The accepted answer is correct, there is no way to set this using one `scale` command.  Here's one way to work around it.

Instead of scaling the slaves at once, scale them one at a time, using an environment variable to set the hostname at each step.  This does defeat the convenience of `scale` a bit, but it seems to work, at least in Compose 1.8.1.

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
master:
  build: .

slave:
  build: .
  hostname: slave${SLAVE_INDEX}
  command: run_slave
```

Run them:

```
$ for i in $(seq 1 5); do SLAVE_INDEX=$i docker-compose scale slave=$i; done
Creating and starting so_slave_1 ... done
Creating and starting so_slave_2 ... done
Creating and starting so_slave_3 ... done
Creating and starting so_slave_4 ... done
Creating and starting so_slave_5 ... done

$ for i in $(docker ps --format  '{{ .Names }}'); do
> echo -n "$i: "; docker inspect --type container $i | jq -r '.[].Config.Hostname'
> done
so_slave_5: slave5
so_slave_4: slave4
so_slave_3: slave3
so_slave_2: slave2
so_slave_1: slave1

$ for i in $(seq 1 5); do docker exec -it so_slave_${i} hostname; done
slave1
slave2
slave3
slave4
slave5
```

Comment: If you're using Compose to generate a stack for Swarm Mode, you do have the option to template the hostname now: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_create/#create-services-using-templates.  This doesn't work in non-Swarm-Mode compose.

Comment: Such a horrible solution, but I think this is the best available. Can't believe they haven't improved this, don't want to mess around with complex scripts just to get a dev environment spun up