# Docker: Run an automatically determined amount of containers

Tags: linux, powershell, docker, dockerfile

I have started working with Docker and so far, everything works. 
Until now, I have created a docker file which creates a container and inside this, runs a dotnet application.

Now, the question comes to me if accomplishing the following task is possible:

I have e.g. 5 Json-Files. One docker container relies on one Json-file due to the dotnet application (the json-file includes credentials which are needed by the dotnet application). 
So, is there a possibility that it is checked how many json-files are locally stored in the path xy, and, depending on the amount, automatically 5 containers are started and, afterwards, one json-file is passed to each of them?

I did not find anything and I don't know what the best approach is for such a scenario. A script would be great, maybe Linux or powershell? I don't think that this task can be realised by a simple docker file - but maybe I am wrong.

Thanks to everyone for any tips. :-)

Comment: Does the application in the container accept the json file as a parameter argument?

Comment: I thought about setting the json file as environment variable. Therefore, I would introdue a new ARG variable, and reference it to set the initial ENV variable dynamically during the build. So when a container is build, the json-file can be specified for every single one. But what is a good way to build the certain amount of containers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a container orchestrator.

The simplest solution would be to write a shell script and spawn container with the JSON file name as an argument. 
You can also select the JSON file to use through the script and only copy this file to the container.

Eventually, consider running these containers through Kubernetes/docker swarm. For Kubernetes, use https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/. We can define templates here. Each JSON file can be named in sequence, and the parameter can be templated.

Eg:
config-1.json
config-2.json

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I think docker compose is the way I would try to go.

Comment: Ups, I klicked the "Add Comment" button way to fast. Do you know if there is a opportunity to scale inside docker compose? So that one container knows which number it is? E.g. Oh, I build as second, so I am container 2

Comment: Not sure if running this through compose is a good idea. Here's a discussion around that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43659410/docker-container-hostname-sequential-number. There is a workaround here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40567032/4389140

Comment: Thanks a million @Palash Goel ! The links answer my question :-)